# Dynamically update a navbar using Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am using the following code snippet from John Morris to investigate how Ajax might work for dynamically updating my menu:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var trigger = $('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 ul li a'),
    container = $('#navbar_content');

    trigger.on('click', function(){
      var $this = $(this), target = $this.data('target');
      container.load(target + '.php');
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

I also have this html code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id='navbar_content'>
    <li class="active"><a href="#" data-target="object1">object1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-target="object2"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-target="object3"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-target="object4"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

which I would like to dynamically replace with this code when object 2 is clicked (to change the class of the selected hyperlink) - there is simlar code in object3.php and object4.php:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id='navbar_content'>
    <li><a href="#" data-target="object1">object1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#" data-target="object2"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-target="object3"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-target="object4"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Everything works well on my first click of object 2, but subsequent clicks of other links will not update the navbar. I think this is related to bindings but I can not figure out what needs to be done to fix this. All suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are overwriting the links inside `#navbar_content`, you need to use event delegation - see https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

So instead of binding to

```
var trigger = $('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 ul li a')
```

you need to bind to your `container` and use event propagation. Try with something like -

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var container = $('#navbar_content');

    container.on('click', 'li a', function(){
      var $this = $(this), target = $this.data('target');
      container.load(target + '.php');
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Sean, I'll get back to this tomorrow and let you know how it went.

Comment: This code works for changing the navbar, but I have extended the idea, and I now wish to update a seperate second div with some other additional content from a PHP source (information about the click menu item) when the navbar is clicked.